# Routing string parameters in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

As I've created a seperate search controller with multiple get methods, I needed to modify the default routes.

SearchController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Object> CompanyByOrderId(long id) { ... }
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Object> CompanyByName(string name) { ... }
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Object> UserByName(string name) { ... }
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ActionById",
        routeTemplate: "api/Search/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Search", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
     );

     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "ActionByName",
         routeTemplate: "api/Search/{action}/{name}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Search", name = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );

      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "DefaultApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );
}
```

Referring to `http://localhost:52498/api/Search/CompanyByOrderId/1` works fine. But calling one of the other methods with a name as parameter results in 404 error. E.g. `http://localhost:52498/api/Search/UserByName/john`

How do I specify that the URI with the string parameter is mapped to the CompanyByName / UserByName methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a constraint to your first route so that it will only match numbers for the {id} parameter:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionById",
    routeTemplate: "api/Search/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Search", id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
);
```

Alternatively you could remove your second route entirely and change your action signatures to use only the {id} parameter:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Object> CompanyByOrderId(long id) { ... }
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Object> CompanyByName(string id) { ... }
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Object> UserByName(string id) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you hard code those routes?  If so, something similar to this should work.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "CompanyByNameRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/Search/CompanyByName/{name},
    defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "CompanyByName", name = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, hard coded it work's. Since there are some more getters than I those I posted and I don't want to register each of them severally, I'd be pleased if someone comes up with a more generic solution.